# JavaScript for...in on array iterates through unenumerable properties

Tags: javascript

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and various other sources, `for...in` iterates over only enumerable properties. By enumerable I assume those which return `false` for `propertyIsEnumerable()`. Still, the following code on [this](http://steamcommunity.com) page

```js
var TstArr = [0];
for (var A in TstArr) {
 console.log("In",TstArr.propertyIsEnumerable(A),TstArr[A]);
};
```

logs this:

```
In false function each()
In false function eachSlice()
In false function all()
In false function any()
```

I know that `for...in` is not advised for arrays and I already suspect that array was extended by Prototype, that is not my question. My question is why it enumerates what it supposedly shouldn't.
This is the same both for FF & Chrome.

Comment: If you are using the Prototype.js library, you should tag that in the question. It extends *Array.prototype*, whose built–in methods aren't enumerable. For me, the result is `In true 0`.

Comment: @RobG Prototype is used on that page but I wasn't using it in the part I had question about. The thing that it's Prototype's methods was my guess.

Comment: Sure, but it explains why the methods were appearing. Running your code snippet doesn't produce the results you say you got, it returns exactly what I'd expect. Noting that Prototype.js is included in the page would have helped with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`propertyIsEnumerable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/propertyIsEnumerable) does test whether the object's **own** property is enumerable. If the object doesn't have an own property with that name, it returns `false`.

Given that those enumerated properties are inherited from `TstArray`s prototype, you'll need to call the method on that object:

```
for (var p in TstArr) {
    console.log(p, Object.getPrototypeOf(TstArr).propertyIsEnumerable(p));
}
```

Comment: I didn't even know this method existed :-/

Comment: For the curious, MDN has full details on [enumerable properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) and [propertyIsEnumerable()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/propertyIsEnumerable).

Comment: @Michael Geary read both pages, first just before asking and second sometime earlier. Looks like they don't outline the ownership requirement for the check good enough. Or maybe it's my reading skills.

Comment: @FelixKling: It's one of those horrible `Object` methods where you usually need to use `Object.prototype.….call` to catch all edge cases.

Comment: @ZeroUnderscoreOu: right at the beginning: *"This method can determine whether the specified property in an object can be enumerated by a for...in loop, **with the exception of properties inherited through the prototype chain**. If the object does not have the specified property, this method returns false."*